# How to include source links in Webpack-bundled code when using Nx in development mode

Tags: node.js, webpack, nrwl-nx

I have an Nx project that has an express application. When I'm running the application in dev mode:

```
nx serve my-app
```

and an error occurs I get a stack trace that links to the webpack bundle, and not the actual source code file:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at /myproject/dist/apps/myapp/webpack:/src/main.ts:133:39
    at /myproject/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Chain.js:15:103
    at /myproject/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/EitherT.js:83:97
    at /myproject/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/ReaderT.js:24:97
    at /myproject/node_modules/fp-ts/lib/Task.js:133:41
```

How can I configure Nx to point to the right file? Note that my logger (tslog) can do this, so it is possible somehow:

```
├» [2023-09-26 14:26:23.681]    INFO    MyApp      [/libs/domain/app/src/MyApp.ts:347]
└» Starting scheduler...
├» [2023-09-26 14:26:23.688]    DEBUG   MyApp      [/libs/domain/operations/src/operation/RegisterOrUpdateUser.ts:27]
└» Registering or updating user with email <...>.
├» [2023-09-26 14:26:23.692]    DEBUG   MyApp      [/libs/domain/operations/src/operation/RegisterOrUpdateUser.ts:33]
└» User with email <...> doesn't exist, creating user.
```

What I've tried so far is to:

- Add `"sourceMap": true,` to the `project.json` file
- Add source mapping in `webpack.config.js`

None of these worked.

Comment: I have the same issue, i am not sure where this "/webpack:" part is coming from or how to disable it :D